# How to change an Immutable array

Tags: reactjs

I am still getting confused with immutability. I have the following Array(with object inside). The name of the array "DEPARTMENTALOBJECT"

```
[{propA: 123, propB: 345},{propA: 234, propB: 353},{propA: 4523, propB: 644}]
```

How can I change the value of propB for the second object

I tried this one but not working as expected

```
Object.assign([], DEPARTMENTALOBJECT[2], {[propB]: 781})
```

-Thanks

Comment: [An **immutable object** (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Comment: you need to create a new array with a new object in it.

Comment: You don't. You create a new array with copied values.

Comment: So I should just do a deep copy of my array and change the value from that copy?

Comment: I have no problem copying it but wanted to see if there is a better way to manipulate object inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new version of `DEPARTMENTALOBJECT` by using a combination of the `map` array method to iterate over the existing values in `DEPARTMENTALOBJECT` and then update the desired element by using the spread (`...`) operator and passing in new values to overwrite the existing values to achieve your desired result.

For example:

```js
const DEPARTMENTALOBJECT = [{propA: 123, propB: 345}, {propA: 234, propB: 353}, {propA: 4523, propB: 644}];

const NEWDEPARTMENTALOBJECT = DEPARTMENTALOBJECT.map((e, i) => i === 2 ? {...e, propB: 781} : e);
```

With result for `NEWDEPARTMENTALOBJECT`:

```js
[
    { propA: 123, propB: 345 },
    { propA: 234, propB: 353 },
    { propA: 4523, propB: 781 },
]
```

Comment: I dont think using map would be the most efficient way here.

Comment: @Billy this is a pretty standard way of getting updated arrays, and the map has only linear time complexity. You could create a copy of the array and then modify directly, however creating a deep copy generally has linear time complexity as well, but also involves a lot more memory.

Comment: I think it would be faster if we just declare the index right instead of doing a map trying to find the index? Like for example DEPARTMENTALOBJECT[2][keyname] = "something value here". I was looking for the most efficient way.

Comment: @Billy that will work, but is a mutation and you asked how to do this without mutating `DEPARTMENTALOBJECT`. Also linear time is quite efficient. Another common way of doing this would be to use `slice`, which is again linear in time.

Comment: Also the map is not just trying to find the appropriate element but also ends up creating a new array.